# Office 2007 Setup prompts for PptLR.cab

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, setup

While running Office 2007 Ultimate Setup on Windows 7 box, I get this error message - "Setup cannot find PowerPoint.en-us\PptLR.cab".

This file is very much present in the setup folder. It gives me an option to choose the correct path of this file, but when I browse and navigate to the folder containing this file, it doesn't show me the CAB file for selection.

I tried installing both from DVD and also running setup from hard disk location.

The same setup media was used earlier for installation on Vista without any issues!

Answer (score 1):

Check the media for any scratches or problems. Next, try to open the CAB file yourself and see if it is readable.

FYI, for comparison - on my Ultimate disk, the file has a creation date/time of 30/10/2006 02:33 and the size is 13,422,356  and has a CRC of 0xA98A52BE

Comment: Yes, I was able to open & extract the CAB file using 7-Zip.  My CAB file size is also 12.7 MB (13,422,356 bytes).  The file creation time shows 30-Nov-2006 4:03PM. I am not sure how to check the CRC.  

The media is a ISO File on my hard disk, that I burnt it to DVD.  Even I tried extracting the ISO file and ran the setup. But still encountering the same problem!

Comment: In my case, that was the problem, a corrupted CAB file. Winrar shows error when try to uncompres it.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by a trial version of Office 2007 being pre-installed on your machine. Check control panel, Programs, Uninstall a program and then uninstall everything with Office in it's name. After this you should be able to install both from the DVD and the HDD.

Comment: I will try this and let you know in a day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: I installed MS Office 13 (365) and uninstalled it after and installed MS Office 2010 again (without rebooting) and it worked as "charm"...
(Before I tried to uninstall and delete everything which has something common with MSO 2010).
PS: Problem occured when I uninstalled MSO 2007 and tried to install MSO 2010.

So if nothing helped you just try to install and uninstall MSO 13 (365) again and after install MSO 2010.

Cheers